# process looping in ntdll!RtlConvertSidToUnicodeString

Tags: windows, winapi, stl

I have a process which uses a stl map and while trying to delete the second item, the process is stuck in a loop. I took a dump using the "userdump". Analyzing the dump shows the process is looping in as the cpu is consumed by that process.

ntdll!RtlConvertSidToUnicodeString
msvcr80!free

Please let me know if anybody came across a problem like this? Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Cant really say if people have faced this problem. But posting some of your code, will really help!

Comment: Do you have code? Can you debug it?

Comment: Quacks like standard heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all symbols and the proper DLLs (Windows Debugging Tools) installed, use [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) to find out what the process really is doing. Taking a memory dump at an arbitrary point will not really help here, since it's the snapshot at some point. In Process Explorer bring up the properties for the process in question, suspend the *process* (not just one thread), then check the stack tab, repeat.

Even for your dump, you can use WinDbg to inspect the call stack (`kb` command) of the various threads you may have.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try the steps suggested by you next time. As of now i am not facing the problem. It seems be a one time glitch... Waiting with crossed fingers!